# Updating entire row or column of a 2D array in JAX

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, jax

I'm new to JAX and writing code that JIT compiles is proving to be quite hard for me. I am trying to achieve the following:

Given an `(n,n)` array `mat` in JAX, I would like to add a `(1,n)` or an `(n,1)` array to an arbitrary row or column, respectively, of the original array `mat`.

If I wanted to add a row array, `r`, to the third row, the numpy equivalent would be,

```
# if mat is a numpy array
mat[2,:] = mat[2,:] + r
```

The only way I know how to update an element of an array in JAX is using `array.at[i].set()`. I am not sure how one can use this to update a row or a column without explicitly using a for-loop.

Comment: you'll find it easier if you adopt the functional style of jax. Don't mutate arrays, define new ones in terms of the old ones. It will take practice to learn how to write things effectively like that but it's the recommended approach, and will work nicely with jit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JAX arrays are immutable, so you cannot do in-place modifications of array entries. But you can accomplish similar results with the [`np.ndarray.at`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.ndarray.at.html) syntax. For example, the equivalent of

```py
mat[2,:] = mat[2,:] + r
```

would be

```py
mat = mat.at[2,:].set(mat[2,:] + r)
```

But you can use the `add` method to be more efficient in this case:

```py
mat = mat.at[2:].add(r)
```

Here is an example of adding a row and column array to a 2D array:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

mat = jnp.zeros((5, 5))

# Create 2D row & col arrays, as in question
row = jnp.ones(5).reshape(1, 5)
col = jnp.ones(5).reshape(5, 1)

mat = mat.at[1:2, :].add(row)
mat = mat.at[:, 2:3].add(col)

print(mat)
# [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 1. 2. 1. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

See [JAX Sharp Bits: In-Place Updates](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#in-place-updates) for more discussion of this.